# Dealing with callback nesting and recursion in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, callback, nested

I've a situation where I found a solution, but I am not happy with it. I'm trying to find out a more elegant solution. Basically a library that:

- sends a request, calls a completion callback when the response stream is returned succesfully
- decodes the stream of the response, but there's a stream decoding error. The error is recoverable since the request may be retried without the troublesome encoding

As concept, the thing is simple: disable the encoding, recursively retry the request. However, the stream may not be consumed at once. It may be passed back to the client code, or it may be wrapped by methods that consume it in specific ways: saving it to a Buffer, or saving it to a file. Therefore it uses an "inner wrapper" aka the method that retrieves the stream and gives the OK for continuing the processing, and the "outer wrapper" that consumes the stream (saveBuffer() in the example code). I wrote some code that explains the thing that bothers me:

```
var Request = function (options) {
    this.options = options;
};

Request.prototype.send = function (callback) {
    this.stream = createStream(function () {
        callback(null, success); // completion callback
    });
    this.stream.pause();
};

// save the stream as Buffer
Request.prototype.saveBuffer = function (callback) {
    var self = this;
    this.stream.on('error', function (err) {
        // unfortunately this err does not appear in this.send
        // as it is a stream decoding error that happens in
        // edge cases after the stream is passed back successfully
        if ("recoverable error") {
            // this is the piece of code that bothers me
            self.options.disableTroublesomeEncoding = true;
            self = new Request(self.options);
            self.send(function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                    return;
                }

                self.saveBuffer(callback);
            });
            return;
        }

        callback(err);
    });

    this.stream.on('success', function () {
        callback(null, self.success());
    });

    this.stream.resume();
}

Request.prototype.success = function () {
    return {
        code: this.stream.code //, etc
    }
};

// client code

var req = new Request(options);

req.send(function (err, res) {
    // if no error, continue
    req.saveBuffer(function (err, success) {
        // handle error or success
        // success is different than req.success()
        // for recoverable errors
    });
});
```

I create a new Request instance internally since the client code is already in saveBuffer() when the decoding error hits and that was the only easy way for reissuing send(). Basically, by assigning the new instance to self (where self = this) works properly internally. To get the proper success status by I have to pass it to the completion callback of the "outer callback". This is the thing that bothers me: req.success() has the wrong values as it doesn't reflect the state of the internally created Request object, but the values returned by the initial request that failed to decode.

Is it possible to have req.success() return the state of the internally created object instead of pointing to the original object?

Comment: how quickly does the encoding fails? Is it possible to do an initial read of the stream before returning it?

Comment: It is a gzip or deflate encoded HTTP stream. The decoding fails after the HTTP headers are received and the stream is piped to the zlib library: var unzip = zlib.createUnzip(); stream = response.pipe(unzip); LE: short answer to your question - no.

Comment: do the headers specify the content type returned?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it is irrelevant as with some responses it is merely a hint, like the file extensions. For some cases I check the actual type after saving the resource and using file/libmagic. The "content-encoding" header specifies how the stream is presented to the client, but that may not be the case. This is revealed only after the decoding starts. I've seen servers claiming content-encoding: gzip, only to actually send plain text responses. Not really standards compliant, but unfortunately I have to deal with the broken parts of the internets.

Comment: It might be possible to pipe the response stream to 2 streams at once. One stream unzips, the other doesn't. You then expose a single custom stream which holds a reference to these 2 streams. On the first read request on your custom stream, you read from the unzipping stream first, if it fails, you set a flag and read from the second stream only. If it succeeds you dispose of the second stream. Just an idea. Not great, but at least you're not buffering everything.